# Convert string to Array of letters and then output each SPAN

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert a string into Array of letters but only using JavaScript (no jQuery)

For now I have worked this out but I know I'm missing more, I know there are jQuery for this but I want to learn more about vanilla JS

```
function myFunction() {
    var str = 'Test';
    var split = str.split("");
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = '<span class="test">' + split + '</span>';
}
myFunction()
```

Comment: The string is already converted to array of letters (try `console.log(split)`), what is your real question now?

Comment: @Marius Check my answer if you are interested in a one-line solution to your issue. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are so close to the answer, you only need to iterate over the array:

```
function myFunction() {
    var str = 'Test';
    var split = str.split("");
    var html = '';
    for(let i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        html += '<span class="test">' + split[i] + '</span>';
    }
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = html;
}
myFunction()
```

Comment: Do you read his mind, how do you know he want every letter on a different `<spam>`?

Comment: `Convert string to Array of letters and then output each SPAN` I just assumed he meant output each into a span :)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I never paid much attention to title, I was looking at the question...

Comment: TBH when you asked this i was "i'm sure i did add each SPAN" gone back looked at doc could not find then after 2 min oh crap it's in the title :D

Answer (score 1):

You can construct the required html string by [mapping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) each letter to a `span` element and then [joining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the result:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var str = 'Test';
    var split = str.split("");
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = split.map(letter => `<span class="test">${letter}</span>`).join('');
}
myFunction()
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function myFunction() {
    var str = 'Test';
    var split = str.split('');
      split.forEach((e)=>{
   var span= document.createElement("span"); 
   var textnode = document.createTextNode(e);
   span.appendChild(textnode);document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(span); 
    })

}
myFunction()
```

Check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8b39gfm6/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in just one-line by spreading your string characters to an array and then map through the array, pushing each character `"e"` wrapped in the `span` tag to your `#demo` div element using the `innerHTML` property like this:

```
[...str].map(e => document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML += `<span class="test">${e}</span>`;
```

---

Check and run the following **Code Snippet** for a practical example of the above:

```js
/* JavaScript */
function myFunction(str) {
    [...str].map(e => document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML += `<span class="test">${e}</span>`
)}

myFunction("Test");
myFunction("Hello");
```

```css
/* CSS */
.test {display: block; background-color: green; margin: 5px 0px;text-align:center; font-size: 20px;}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<div id="demo"></div>
```